# Constructor functions

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

In this code here, does theRun() function act as a constructor?

```
contract theRun {
                
        address private admin;
        
        function theRun() {
            admin = msg.sender;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that compiler is not giving you any error? Because you haven't mentioned scope in your `theRun()`.
And no, the `theRun()` won't act as constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, Since `solidity 0.4.23`, constructors needs to be specified using the `constructor` keyword, constructors are optional.

So you can declare your constructor using a function with the same name as your contract, IF you’re using a version older than 0.4.23

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't.

The most and obvious reason is that **a function can never have the same name as the contract.**

- Function can only be called at a defined time to perform a specific task and it requires a valid return type.
- Constructor initializes a created object and have no return type.